# How to insert 3 source tags with different attribute values using only javascript?

Tags: javascript

In my HTML I have a picture tag that has an image as a child. Using JavaScript, how do I insert 3 source tags that have 2 attributes with different values? I've placed my current code and the expected results below.

I am able to insert the same strings to the value. But, I am not able to make every string different.

I start with this code

```js
const PIC = document.querySelector('picture');
const IMAGE = document.querySelector('img');

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var source = document.createElement('source'); //created Source element
  var media = '(max-width:250px)';

  source.setAttribute('media', media); //Set its media attribute 
  //created srcset attribute
  var imgSrc = IMAGE.getAttribute('src'); //Img src 
  var width = 200;
  var arr = [];
  // strip off last 8 chars of image name
  imgSrc = imgSrc.slice(0, -8);
  arr[i] = imgSrc + '-' + width + '.jpg';
  width += 200;
  var srcset = arr.join(); //imgSrc + '-' + width + '.jpg'; 

  source.setAttribute('srcset', srcset);
  //  console.log(source.outerHTML)
  var insert = PIC.insertBefore(source, PIC.firstChild);
}
console.log(PIC.outerHTML)
```

```html
<picture>
  <img src="images/turtle2-800.jpg" alt="sea turtle">
</picture>
```

And need to create this code. Only Using Javascript.

```
<picture>
    <source media="(max-width:250px)" srcset="images/turtle2-200.jpg">
    <source media="(max-width:450px)" srcset="images/turtle2-400.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width:451px)" srcset="images/turtle2-800.jpg">
    <img src="images/turtle2-800.jpg" alt="sea turtle">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the widths outside in arrays:

```js
const PIC = document.querySelector('picture');
const IMAGE = document.querySelector('img');

var widths = [200,400,800], mW = [250,450,451]

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var source = document.createElement('source'); //created Source element
  var media = '(max-width:'+mW[i]+'px)';
  source.setAttribute('media', media); //Set its media attribute 
  //created srcset attribute
  var imgSrc = IMAGE.getAttribute('src'); //Img src 
  // strip off last 8 chars of image name
  imgSrc = imgSrc.slice(0, -8);
  var srcset = imgSrc + '-' + widths[i] + '.jpg'; 
  source.setAttribute('srcset', srcset);
  var insert = PIC.insertBefore(source, PIC.firstChild);
}
console.log(PIC.outerHTML)
```

```html
<picture>
  <img src="images/turtle2-800.jpg" alt="sea turtle">
</picture>
```